# Automatically convert "..." to "\ldots"

Tags: editors, automation

Is there a way to automatically convert a basic string into a command, for example converting instances of `...` to `\ldots`? I have to work with a large number of plaintext files, and doing a dozen find/replace operations for each file is rather inconvenient.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Seems like a job that could easily be done outside of TeX with a simple `sed` script.  But how would you want to handle the case where these should instead be `\cdots`?

Comment: @PeterGrill something like `find -name '*.tex' -print0| xargs -0 sed -i 's/\.\.\./\\ldots/'` :)

Comment: @PeterGrill In text, `...` should always be `\ldots{}`, so the case of `\cdots{}` might not apply to the OP.

Comment: With for example [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) you can do one find/replace operation simultaneously on as many files as your memory allows to open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some fonts that turn `...` into Unicode Character 02026 "Horizontal Ellipsis" `…`, e.g. Linux Libertine and [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/), which have this transformation as part of the "Common" Ligature set (OpenType feature `liga`). Since both fonts activate the "Common" ligatures by default, you don't need to do anything but use the respective font. Here's an example of `liga` on and off, with the output, and the OCR Layer of the PDF, i.e. what's copy-pastable and findable with the search function:

```
% compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

\libertine Linux Libertine:

{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-liga} Hey ... what’s up?}

{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+liga} Hey ... what’s up?}

\fontspec{Junicode} Junicode: % you need to have the font installed

{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-liga} Hey ... what’s up?}

{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+liga} Hey ... what’s up?}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

```
Linux Libertine:
Hey ... what’s up?
Hey … what’s up?
Junicode:
Hey ... what’s up?
Hey … what’s up?
```

(Adobe Reader 10.1.4 on Win7 is actually able to find all four three-dot combinations if you search for either `...` or `…`. Sumatra PDF 2.1.1 only finds the two specific ones for each.)