# LaTeX: automatically convert "..." to "\ldots" upon \input

Tags: input, ellipsis

I already read [Automatically convert "..." to "\ldots"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78607/automatically-convert-to-ldots) but this question was asked/answered to help the asker save a lot of replace operations through several files.

In my case, I'm trying to `\input` several files of separate scenes (for a novel) that conform a whole story. I'm interested in keeping the separate files as plain as possible, which means I want to use the fewer TeX/LaTeX commands. Reason is I'll be sending the separate files for revision, and having a lot of `\ldots` in text makes for a harder reading/revising. However, I would like to use a font other than Linux Libertine or Junicode, so the referenced solution will not primarily work for my document.

I could, of course, wait until the end of the revision process and then batch-replace. However, I was hoping for a better -more programmatic way- of replacing "..." with an ellipsis, without actually modifying the source files to replace each with `\ldots`.

**Example of `main.tex`:**

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,9pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mynovel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \story{stories/first_story.tex}
\end{document}
```

**Example of `mynovel.sty`:**

```
\ProvidesPackage{mynovel}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
% Most code here is to provide a lettrine automatically
\def\capitalize#1#2 {
    \lettrine[lhang=1,nindent=0pt,loversize=0.5,lines=2]{#1}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\story}[1]{
    % some code here explicitly omitted
    \expandafter\capitalize\@@input#1
}
```

**Example of `stories/first_story.tex`:**

```
Había una vez un hombre. El hombre dijo:

---Buenos días... ¿me da una taza de café?
```

Comment: Have you considered writing in markdown and using pandoc to convert to LaTeX when needed?

Comment: @lorenzo-pena are you going to be using Linux Libertine or Junicode for your final output?  If so I don't understand what your problem would be.  Have you tried `\input <file>` in your master document and that did not convert the periods to ellipsis in the `<file>` portion of your final output?

Comment: @Seamus, I wouldn't want to write in markdown.

Comment: @lorenzo-peña what would you MWE look like?

Comment: @AFeldman, while Linux Libertine and Junicode would solve the problem for me, I like `ebgaramond` (MikTeX 2.9). Is there any way to make Junicode work for me like that?

Comment: @lorenzo-peña do you mean "make ebgaramond" work for me like that?"  If so I think there might very well be.  Why don't you post a MWE both for your master file, and an example of your input file.

Comment: your spanish characters work right? I fear your accents and opening questions may not be working...

Comment: @erreka they are working good, `inputenc` takes care of it.

Comment: that's odd: your accepted answer implies LuaLaTeX, so you shouldn't be using `inputenc` at all...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can use LuaLaTeX, i.e., the LaTeX *format* with the LuaTeX *engine* (instead of the pdfTeX engine), it is straightforward to write a Lua function that replaces all instances of `...` with `\dots` "on the fly", at a very early stage of the compilation process (*before* TeX starts its usual processing).

The following example sets up such a Lua function, named `dots2ellipses`, and provides two LaTeX macros, named `\dotstoellipsisON` and `\dotstoellipsisOFF`, which activate and deactivate the operation of the Lua function.

[image]

(The code uses "Arno Pro" rather than "EB Garamond" since the former generates a more easily visible difference of the appearance of "..." and "\dots".)

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arno Pro} % for a clear difference between "..." and "\dots"

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function dots2ellipses ( buff ) 
   return ( buff:gsub ( "%.%.%." , "\\dots{}" ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code: macros to switch Lua function on/off
\newcommand\dotstoellipsisON{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", dots2ellipses, "dots2ellipses" )}}
\newcommand\dotstoellipsisOFF{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", "dots2ellipses" )}}

\begin{document}
\dotstoellipsisON
here ... there ... everywhere --- with ``\textbackslash dots''

\dotstoellipsisOFF
here ... there ... everywhere --- without ``\textbackslash dots''

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the substitution scheme was also helpful in dealing with broken `---.` and `---,` across lines, I am now automatically enclosing them in `\mbox{}`.

Comment: Does this method have any advantage over defining a feature (e.g., `feature dlig {sub \period \period \period by \ellipsis;} dlig;`)?

Comment: @Thérèse - Not sure if it amounts to an "advantage", but the Lua function given in the answer does exactly one thing (and only one thing...). In contrast, depending on the font that's in use, turning on the `dlig` feature may activate other `dlig`-related activities -- in addition to the replacement of `...` with `\dots{}` that would be specified in a feature file. Separately, the code given in the answer allows for easy activation and deactivation of the Lua function, without having to switch to a different font family (i.e., one for which the feature file isn't being loaded).

Comment: with encTeX you spare a Lua function with an extended TeX primitive.

Comment: @erreka - I'm afraid I'm utterly unfamiliar with encTeX. Would you mind explaining what it is and how your comment relates to the posting and/or my answer?

Comment: @Mico: you can check what is encTeX on [CTAN's documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enctex) and related places; and it is related to your answer this way: the OP seems to be using some 8bit TeX engine (clue: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`), and encTeX was designed precisely to handle UTF8 on 8bit TeXes; besides that, encTeX's primitive `\mubyte` can be used to turn any byte sequence (like the three dots) into a token (like \dots), as the OP was requesting. So the OP didn't require LuaTeX at all.

Answer (score 6):

If you use any format (Plain, LaTeX) with an active encTeX engine you can write something like this:

```
\mubyte\dots...\endmubyte
\mubytein=1 % make it 0 to turn off conversion

something ... or another
```

and you get the expected output. encTeX is available in 8bit TeX engines (Knuth, eTeX, pdfTeX).

Comment: @LorenzoPeña There exists a possibility to re-generate LaTeX format with encTeX activated. If you do this then you can use `\mubyte` in LaTeX too.

Comment: only encTeX is needed; csplain is not required.

Comment: @wipet Can this solution be used with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @AFeldman No, these engines have totally different input processor. They have other tools to control the behaviour at input processor level (lua scripts for example).

Comment: @AFeldman you may request the inclusion of the encTeX primitives on those engines, of course...

Answer (score 2):

Try this, compiling with xelatex:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{ebgaramond}
    \usepackage{xesearch}
\UndoBoundary{.}
\SearchList{list1}{\ldots}{...}

\begin{document}

    Hello ... World

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any workaround to make it work with input files? It works when I type text directly into the `main.tex` file, but not when inputting content from other files.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña not that I could find.  Kudos to Mico for a fully working answer.

Comment: @AFeldman ... if you happen to be using LuaLaTeX.